# In a wordpress post, display the list of posts that belong to the same category as the current post but exclude the current post itself

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

On my blog, I have a category called "TGIF XACML". At the end of each post, I want to display posts in the same category except for the current post using the wordpress short code

```
[display-posts category="tgif-xacml"]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically exclude the current post. The reference page for [display-posts](http://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/) does not list that as an option. Is there a way?

If you want to see the current state, check out this [example](http://www.webfarmr.eu/2013/09/tgif-xacml-whats-a-xacml-combining-algorithm/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the shortcode, but using functions you could do it like this:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $this_post = $post->ID;

    $related_query = new WP_Query( $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category' => 'tgif-xacml',
        'post__not_in' => array($this_post)
    ));
?>
```

Comment: Yes I saw that somewhere. I don't suppose there's a one-to-one mapping between short code and underlying functionality. Short codes do require implementation, right?